# How to set OnitemClick in custom listview

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, onitemclicklistener

I created a listview using listview adapter that extends base adapter.

It works fine. but I need to add onitemClick Listener to listview, when I click a list item it go to another activity ,along with the listitem.how can we do this ?

This is my code in the listview adapter

```
public class listviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    String FIRST_COLUMN = Constant.FIRST_COLUMN;
    String SECOND_COLUMN = Constant.SECOND_COLUMN;
    String THIRD_COLUMN = Constant.THIRD_COLUMN;
    String FOURTH_COLUMN = Constant.FOURTH_COLUMN;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
    Activity activity;

    public listviewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
       TextView txtFirst;
       TextView txtSecond;
       TextView txtThird;
       TextView txtFourth;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi=convertView;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater =  activity.getLayoutInflater();

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.requestcard_columnsdetails, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();




                holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
                holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.from);
                holder.txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.to);
                holder.txtFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
            holder.txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
            holder.txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
            holder.txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
            holder.txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));



        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And I populated list items in the main activity using

```
int a,b;
list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
for ( a=0; a<outputString.length;a++){
    HashMap<String,String> temp1 = new  HashMap<String,String>();
    temp1.put( FIRST_COLUMN,outputString[a][0]);
    temp1.put(SECOND_COLUMN, outputString[a][1]);
    temp1.put(THIRD_COLUMN, outputString[a][4]);
    temp1.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, outputString[a][5]);
    list.add(temp1);
}
listviewAdapter adapter = new listviewAdapter(this, list);
lview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> along with the listitem

if you want to get some data from the ListItem, just use `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` inside the listener which was already mentioned. This will return a corresponding `Object` that you can perform further actions with

```
   HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
  String one = map.get("key");
  String two = map.get("key2");

  Intent next = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
  next.putExtra("One", one);
  next.putExtra("Two", two);
  startActivity(next);
```

Get it in your second Activity:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 String one = extras.getStringExtra("One");
 String two = extras.getStringExtra("Two");
```

Comment: hi , i need to pass that item to next classs, how it is possible?

Comment: you need to pass not the item itself but the data it holds. Using getItemAtPosition(position) will return a HashMap in your case. Use the get methods to obtain Strings from this HashMap and then put them as extra to the Intent

Comment: then how to get that values from hashmap?

Comment: I added some sample code. You need to do something like that in your listener

Comment: hi Maver, i have one doubt more, how to get the selected item index in the listview

Comment: @SibinF before making any further explanations, I highly suggest you to watch the video where the creator of ListView tells how it works, believe me you won't regret watching it http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=wDBM6wVEO70   This will help you to understand the functionality of the ListView in detail. Best regards, Mav

Answer (score 1):

Create your onItemClickListener in your listview like this:

```
lview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
     Intent intent = new intent(mainactivity.this, target.class);
     // maybe put some extra arguments to the intent 
     startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

To put your extra data to the next activity use your intent:
[Intent doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: how i get the itm id in the next class? i need to pass clicked item to the next class, how it possible

Comment: intent.putExtra("id",id)

And get it back in the second activity.

Comment: I linked the doc in my answer. It gives you a longer explanation about how to put extra data.

Comment: no yar.. i know about intent, but can u  understand my exact problem, see, when i clicking the one item , i want to get item id, position , item value in the next class , howw it possible?

Comment: Intent is the only way to communicate with other acitivies. They can use the get Methods. Just put your id and other required values in the intent. If you click on an item, android will use your onClickListener and the id is your zerobased click item.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setOnItemClickListener`:

```
lview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, secondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
 });
```

Comment: how i  get the item id in the next class

Comment: also i need to pass the item array,outputString[a][0]) this value to next class

Comment: use intent.putExtra(key,Value)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
        {

         Intent myIntent = new Intent(Current_Activity.this,Next_Activity.class);
         startActivity(myIntent);
}
});
```